# Python: obtener las keys correspondientes a los valores mínimos de un diccionario

Tags: python

Tengo un diccionario con los siguientes valores

```
       {'Adrián': 2, 'Juan': 2, 'Adrian': 1, 'AD': 1, 'Adr': 2, 'aDRIAN': 1, 'Adri': 2, 'DRI': 1, 'Pepe': 3, 'Prueba': 1, 'Preiba': 1}
```

he intentado coger los valores mínimos con esta opción

```
       prueba=min(workers_valores, key=workers_valores.get)
       print(prueba)
       Adrian
```

pero solo me da el valor Adrian y no los demás valores que tiene un valor 1. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que me devuelva todos los valores mínimos y no solo el primero que encuentra?

Comment: ¿cómo quieres que sea la salida? no queda claro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `min()` no te sirve para eso, ya que devuelve sólo uno de los mínimos en caso de empates.

Creo que una solución para un caso así sería crear un diccionario inverso, en el que las claves sean los números 1, 2, etc.. y los valores sean las listas de nombres que corresponden a esos valores.

Ese diccionario inverso puede crearse con pocas líneas de código:

```
from collections import defaultdict

valores_workers = defaultdict(list)
for worker, valor in workers_valores.items():
  valores_workers[valor].append(worker)
```

En tu caso el resultado en la variable `valores_workers` sería:

```
{1: ['Adrian', 'AD', 'aDRIAN', 'DRI', 'Prueba', 'Preiba'],
 2: ['Adrián', 'Juan', 'Adr', 'Adri'],
 3: ['Pepe']})
```

Ahora basta extraer de ahi la lista que corresponda a la clave mínima:

```
>>> print(valores_workers[min(valores_workers)])
['Adrian', 'AD', 'aDRIAN', 'DRI', 'Prueba', 'Preiba']
```

Comment: Funciona genial, no sabía yo la estrategia de darle la vuelta al diccionario, agrupar los "valores" y después seleccionar el grupo con los valores menores. Muchas gracias @abulafia

Answer (score 1):

Cuando son pocos elementos, lo mejor es hacer dos pasos. El primero para obtener el mínimo valor, y el segundo para obtener las claves:

```py
minimo = min(workers_valores.values())
workers = [k for k,v in workers_valores.items() if v == minimo]
```

También se podría implementar una solución más iteractiva:

```py
minimo = float('+inf')
workers = []

for k,v in workers_valores.items():
    if v < minimo:
        minimo = v
        workers = [k]
    elif v == minimo:
        workers.append(k)

print(workers)
```

Pero la función `min` está tan optimizada en python que el diccionario tendría que ser gigantesco como para que se note mejora con esta implementación.